# Django form.is_valid always returning true

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm new to Django and python and am trying to learn it from a book. In the code below I'm trying to make sure password1 and password2 are the same but it doesn't seem to run the clean_password2 validation because it always returns true even if they have different values.

```
import re
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=u'Username', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label=u'Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label= u'Password',
        widget = forms.PasswordInput()
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label= u'Password (Again)',
        widget = forms.PasswordInput()
    )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
        return password2
```

Comment: To perform validation on multiple fields (exactly this kind of use case) you should override the Form's `clean()` method. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any validator that requires access to more than one field should be part of the `clean()`  method not the `clean_<filedname>()` method.  Check out how django-registration does what you're looking for: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/58eef8330b0f/registration/forms.py#cl-57

Comment: Thanks man. That example code really helped as my code formatting was also not indented correctly and the function was not even being recognized. I'm a real noob with Python.

Comment: I didn't even think that might be a problem (when I edited your question code formatting).

Whitespace is significant in Python, make sure to keep that in mind, it signifies your block level.

Answer (score 3):

If you are cleaning two fields that depend on each other, you should override the form's `clean()` method. You can read more [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're checking `form.is_valid()` rather than `form.is_valid`? It's a method, not a property.